# 503 Error on First Node Web App using Express on Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, express, web, web-deployment

I have my first application build in node using express and it works fine locally. I do however, have a problem when trying to deploy it. I had left out favicon.ico path in my app.js which I fixed thanks to the (error) web logs on GAE, redeployed and over came the 500 issue on my 3rd attempt (maxed out cpu instance allocation on 2nd attempt due to app.yaml not manually setting instance count I fixed it) and got a 503 error.

[image: Front End Page Error Msg]

As the page indicates, its not serving data and I have no web log entries of any type to look at on GAE.

[image: Project Instance Web Logs]

When I look at my back end instance status, its returning serving.
[image: Back End Project Status]

**Any idea when i will get service and am I doing anything wrong?**

The deployment script has some kerberos depreciation warnings extracted as follows:

npm WARN deprecated less-middleware@0.1.12: Updated API and improved functionality.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN prefer global ycssmin@1.0.1 should be installed with -g

**

- 2nd message ext

**

../lib/kerberosgss.c:36:0: warning: ignoring #pragma clang diagnostic [-Wunknown-pragmas]
 #pragma clang diagnostic push
 ^
../lib/kerberosgss.c:37:0: warning: ignoring #pragma clang diagnostic [-Wunknown-pragmas]
 #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
 ^
../lib/kerberosgss.c: In function 'authenticate_gss_client_wrap':
../lib/kerberosgss.c:446:19: warning: variable 'server_conf_flags' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   char buf[4096], server_conf_flags;
                   ^
../lib/kerberosgss.c: At top level:
../lib/kerberosgss.c:1236:0: warning: ignoring #pragma clang diagnostic [-Wunknown-pragmas]
 #pragma clang diagnostic pop
 ^

**

- 3rd message ext

**

../lib/kerberosgss.c:36:0: warning: ignoring #pragma clang diagnostic [-Wunknown-pragmas]
 #pragma clang diagnostic push
 ^
../lib/kerberosgss.c:37:0: warning: ignoring #pragma clang diagnostic [-Wunknown-pragmas]
 #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
 ^
../lib/kerberosgss.c: In function 'authenticate_gss_client_wrap':
../lib/kerberosgss.c:446:19: warning: variable 'server_conf_flags' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   char buf[4096], server_conf_flags;
                   ^
../lib/kerberosgss.c: At top level:
../lib/kerberosgss.c:1236:0: warning: ignoring #pragma clang diagnostic [-Wunknown-pragmas]
 #pragma clang diagnostic pop
 ^

Any help for this GAE newbie would be much appreciated.. :-)

Comment: I got that error in case of improper domain allocation but that certainly isn't the case here. Where is 503 mentioned btw?

Comment: `For resources that are required to initiate a request, when the resource is depleted, App Engine by default returns an HTTP 403 or 503 error code for the request instead of calling a request handler. The following resources have this behavior:

Bandwidth, incoming and outgoing
Instance hours`

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#How_Resources_are_Replenished

Comment: Thanks @GandalftheWhite for the feedback. As its my first app <50mb in express on GAE, I may try using the GAE sample app and deploy it to see if the problem is in my build or GAE issue. I have made corrections to my build config for GAE via app.js and app.yaml so maybe after I see GAEs sample build work, I'll go back and revise my own before trying again to deploy. Seeing the code work in runtime helps me gain a lower level understanding of how the app layer works with GAE storage and infrastructure layers. Logs are great for that! Will post on how I do over the coming days...

Comment: Great John. Keep me posted. I wish I could help more.